# WordPress - Default .htaccess is not working on Godaddy

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have created a beta version www.myhouseinthecloud.com/beta of my client site to do further development but having hard time due to rewrite. Its redirecting me root www.myhouseinthecloud.com all the time.

Here is default .htaccess I have got from Wordpress:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /beta/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /beta/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Site is working fine if I am using id instead of permalinks.

I have Godaddy shared hosting so cannot access apache directly. Please guide me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: i think your mod_rewrite is not enable from server. to make it enable please  follow instruction from this article. link : https://anandnayi.wordpress.com/2015/07/04/404-not-found-apache-centos/